# use python requests to submit a form and get results

Tags: python, xml, forms, post, python-requests

I am not familiar with requests of python. I need to do one thing. here's a link:https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&query_format=advanced&resolution=---&resolution=FIXED&resolution=INVALID&resolution=WONTFIX&resolution=DUPLICATE&resolution=WORKSFORME&resolution=INCOMPLETE&resolution=SUPPORT&resolution=EXPIRED&resolution=MOVED&order=bug_id&limit=10

There is a button of xml below. If you click this button, you will get a xml page. I hope I can use python code to automatically get the xml content.

the html on that page of the xml button is :

> ```
> <form method="post" action="show_bug.cgi">
> <input type="hidden" name="ctype" value="xml">
> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="35">
> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="36">
> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="37">
> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="38">
> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="39">
> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="41">
> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="42">
> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="43">
> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="51">
> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="61">
> <input type="hidden" name="excludefield" value="attachmentdata">
> <input type="submit" value="XML" id="xml">
> </form>
> ```

I tried to use requests. I tried code like this:

```
import requests
values = { 'submit': 'xml'}
req = requests.post('https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&query_format=advanced&resolution=---&resolution=FIXED&resolution=INVALID&resolution=WONTFIX&resolution=DUPLICATE&resolution=WORKSFORME&resolution=INCOMPLETE&resolution=SUPPORT&resolution=EXPIRED&resolution=MOVED&order=bug_id&limit=10',data=values)
print req.text
```

but I got errors.

can someone help me to point out the right usage of requests? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Jud's help. He solved my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install `requests`? If you get import errors you probably don't have all the dependencies installed. See the discussion here: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/513.

Also, it looks like you're hitting the wrong URL. You don't want to GET the original `buglist.cgi`, you want to POST to `show_bug.cgi`, since that's the target of the form action. You also need to include all the values of the hidden form fields:

```
import requests
values = {}
values['ctype'] = 'xml'
# Multiple values for the same name are handled via array
values['id'] = [35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 51, 61]
values['excludefield'] = 'attachmentdata'
req = requests.post('https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi', data=values)
print req.text
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already fixed the import error. but I don't know how to simulate this action, on the page of https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&query_format=advanced&resolution=---&resolution=FIXED&resolution=INVALID&resolution=WONTFIX&resolution=DUPLICATE&resolution=WORKSFORME&resolution=INCOMPLETE&resolution=SUPPORT&resolution=EXPIRED&resolution=MOVED&order=bug_id&limit=10 and click the xml button?

Comment: Did you fix the URL as I also suggested?

Comment: Yes @Jud I tried but the page https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi is totally different page(not xml).

Comment: I forgot to add the additional form fields, that's likely the problem.

Comment: I guess so. but how to deal with hidden fields? I am so sorry

Comment: You add the fields by building a dictionary with name:value pairs. See my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
values = { 'submit': 'xml'}
req = requests.post('https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&query_format=advanced&resolution=---&resolution=FIXED&resolution=INVALID&resolution=WONTFIX&resolution=DUPLICATE&resolution=WORKSFORME&resolution=INCOMPLETE&resolution=SUPPORT&resolution=EXPIRED&resolution=MOVED&order=bug_id&limit=10',data=values)
print req.text
```

seems to work for me.

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't express clearly before. I edited my question. But get still doesn't work.

Comment: @user1167910 what is the error you are getting? Without the error, I'm shooting in the dark.

Comment: sorry, i got an error ImportError: No module named certifi what does it mean?

Comment: Oh I fixed that. But I still get some html thing. Not the xml I want.

Comment: That API call looks very nasty.Check out what the curl command looks like as generated by Chrome. http://pastebin.com/QBqMsDCH